# replace values in a nested list with values from another matrix

Tags: r

I have a list of 28 elements like the following which are combinations of 8 elements two by two (SG1, SG2, ... SG8):

```
str(combinations)
List of 28
 $ : chr [1:2] "SG1" "SG2"
 $ : chr [1:2] "SG1" "SG3"
 $ : chr [1:2] "SG1" "SG4"
...
```

I have stored the results of a t.test in an object:

```
results <- lapply(seq_along(combinations), function (n) {
  mydatatemp <- mydata[with(mydata, Subgroup %in% unlist(combinations2[n]) & Group %in% c("G1", "G3")),]
  result <- t.test(mydatatemp[
                   mydatatemp$Subgroup == sapply(combinations[n], "[",1),4],
                   mydatatemp[mydatatemp$Subgroup == sapply(combinations[n], "[", 2),4],
                   alternative="two.sided", var.equal=TRUE)
             return(result)})
```

and my `str(result)` is like this, of course 28 list elements one after another like this one:

```
List of 28
 $ :List of 9
  ..$ statistic  : Named num -6.9
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
  ..$ parameter  : Named num 38
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
  ..$ p.value    : num 3.33e-08
  ..$ conf.int   : atomic [1:2] -0.301 -0.164
  .. ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
  ..$ estimate   : Named num [1:2] 0.196 0.429
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "mean of x" "mean of y"
  ..$ null.value : Named num 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "difference in means"
  ..$ alternative: chr "two.sided"
  ..$ method     : chr " Two Sample t-test"
  ..$ data.name  : chr [1:2] "mydatatemp[mydatatemp$Subgroup == sapply(combinations[n], \"[\", 1),  and mydatatemp[mydatatemp$Subgroup == sapply(combinations[n], \"[\""| __truncated__ "    4] and     4]"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

how can I rename all of the `$data.name` elements `chr [1:2]` with the following `paste` code?

```
paste(matrix(unlist(combinations), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)[,1], matrix(unlist(combinations), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)[,2], sep = " vs. ")
```

the reason I am doing this is to replace those ugly looking characters in the $data.name element.

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(result, function(x) {x[["data.name"]] <-paste(....); x})`

Comment: @akrun it access the **data.name** in each list and paste the entire 28 combinations to that element! instead of pasting one by one. how to correct this?